# expo calendar– Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=14 "Calendar has no source"

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting an error running the function trying to create the calendar to store on iCal. It says "Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=14 "Calendar has no source" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Calendar has no source}]". I assume it has to do with the sourceID even though I have that.

This is my function:

```
const iCalID = await Calendar.createCalendarAsync({
      title: 'Ahead',
      color: colors.mainRed,
      entityType: Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT,
      sourceID: this.props.iCalSourceID
    });
```

the iCalSourceID is found like this:

```
const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(); //caldav calendar will contain the sourceID
      const caldavCalendar = calendars.find(calendar => calendar.source.type === 'caldav');
      sourceID = caldavCalendar.source.id;
```

It is properly returning the sourceID so I know I have the right one. But whether I use it with props or hard code in my devices sourceID it still comes up wrong. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Nope! I was never able to resolve this and had to instead make users create a calendar called "ahead" and then grab that one and use that. Pain in the butt.